# Ao acionar um evento em um elemento array(com querySelectAll) acionar só um elemento de outro array(tambémcom querySelectAll)

Tags: javascript, html, css, array

No código que segue abaixo, gostaria que ao passar e retirar o mouse (*mouseover* e *mouseout*) sobre um `li`, a alteração fosse feita só no elemento correspondente a essa `li`, no caso, as tags `a` e `i` dentro da `li`, da mesma forma que acontece com o CSS do código (*background* e *color* da tag `i` alterados com *hover*). O problema que tenho agora é que quando aciono o evento, em vez de alterar só o elemento dentro da `li` em que o mouse está sobre no momento, todos os elementos são afetados de uma vez.

Pra ficar melhor segue o link do codepen com o código completo: http://codepen.io/RaoniSousa/pen/wJqdNP

Agradeço se puderem ajudar.

```
function abc() {

    var myLi = document.querySelectorAll('li'),
        icons = document.querySelectorAll('li i'),        

    //MOUSEOVER
    function changeI() {
        'use strict';
        if (icons.length) {
            for (var i = 0; i < icons.length; i++) {
                icons[i].style.fontSize = '2em';
            }
        }
    }
    //MOUSEOUT
    function backI() {
        'use strict';
        if (icons.length) {
            for (var i = 0; i < icons.length; i++) {
                icons[i].style.fontSize = '1em';
            }
        }
    }
    if (myLi.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < myLi.length; i++) {
            myLi[i].addEventListener("mouseover", changeI);
            myLi[i].addEventListener("mouseout", backI);
        }
    }
}
abc();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu erro principal é que está passando o array com todos os elementos na hora de alterar o estilo deles, você quer alterar o próprio elemento somente, o `this`.

```
var cresce = function() {
  this.style.fontSize = "2em";
}

var diminui = function() {
  this.style.fontSize = "1em"
}

// essa variável terá um array dentro
var lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');

// aí é só passar por ela e incluir os eventos
for (var el, ix = 0; ix < lis.length; ix++) {
    el = lis[ix];
    console.log(el);
    el.addEventListener('mouseover', cresce);
    el.addEventListener('mouseout', diminui);
}
```

A solução do Sergio tem as vantagens de ser uma função só e de usar o retorno de função do javascript, que é bem legal mas é difícil de entender quando você está aprendendo a programar. Espero que essa solução fique mais clara, apesar de ser menos eficiente.

Comment: Bom ver também tua solução, pra ver que tem várias formas de resolver um problema, não tinha pensado no 'this', deu certo, obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Acho que estás a complicar. Em primeiro lugar isso pode ser feito só com CSS, assim:

```css
* {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow: border-box;
    position: relative;
}

body {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: #898989;
}

#container {
    width: 1030px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none!important;
    outline: 0!important;
    border: 0!important
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: 0!important;
    border: 0!important
}

li {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}

img {
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto
}

footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 13em;
    background-color: #a8a8a8;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #e0e0e0
}

#footFlex {
    width: 80%;
    display: flex;
}

#footFlex > div:not(p){
    margin-top: 6%!important
}

#footFlex ul {
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5em;
}

#footFlex li {
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .5s;
    height: 2.5em;
}

#footFlex li:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 5em;
}

#footFlex li:hover a{
    color: #722872;
    font-size: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
}

#footFlex li i:hover{
    background-color: transparent;
}

#footFlex li a{
  line-height: 1em;
    transition: all .5s;
    color: #fff
}

#footFlex div:first-child p:nth-child(2){
    width: 65%;
    left: 17.5%
}

#footFlex div p:nth-child(1){
    font-size: 1.3em
}

#footFlex div:first-child p:nth-child(2) a{
    color: #722872;
    font-weight: 400;
}

#footFlex div:first-child p:nth-child(2) a:hover {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #722872!important
}

#footFlex div:first-child p:first-child, #footFlex div:nth-child(2) p:first-child {
    margin-bottom: 1em
}

footer + div {
    height: 5.6em;
    background-color: #722872;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #e0e0e0;
    line-height: 5.6em;
    text-align: center
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="FreeCodeCamp.css">
</head>

<body id="about" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">
 
    <footer>
    <div id="footFlex">
       <div>           
           <p>ABOUT THIS PAGE</p>
           <p>Made with <i class="fa fa-fw fa-music"></i> and <i class="fa fa-fw fa-coffee"></i> by <a href="">Justin Sane.</a></p>
       </div>
       <div>
           <p>AROUND THE WEB</p>
           <ul>
              <li><a rel="nofollow" class="button social" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/hallaathrad"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
              <li><a rel="nofollow" class="button social" href="https://github.com/hallaathrad"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-github"></i></a></li>
              <li><a rel="nofollow" class="button social" href="https://twitter.com/hallaathrad"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
              <li><a rel="nofollow" class="button social" href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/hallaathrad/" title="My Flickr"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-flickr"></i></a></li>
           </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
    </footer>
    <div>qlip © 2017. All Rights Reversed</div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Javascript.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

E se quiseres usar JavaScript podes passar diretamente os elementos e o tamanho para evitar mais logo ter de iterar tudo:

```
function changeI(el, size) {
    'use strict';
  return function(){
    el.style.fontSize = size;
  }
}

if (liBArray.length) {
    for (var i = 0; i < liB.length; i++) {
        liBArray[i].addEventListener("mouseover", changeI(iconsArray[i], '2em'));
        liBArray[i].addEventListener("mouseout", changeI(iconsArray[i], '1em'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu estava preparando a resposta usando o [`transform scale`](https://repl.it/GUxY/0) kk

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss e seria uma boa resposta. Coloca também!

Comment: Antes fiz com css, mas o lance do js foi mais pra estudo mesmo, sou novo na área e fiquei curioso. Valeu pelas dicas.

Comment: Entendi tua solução, muito boa, mas quando vou executar meu teste com ela não funciona e no console aparece: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
at HTMLLIElement.<anonymous>, 

que é relacionado à expressão: el.style.fontSize = size;

Qual é o problema aí?

Obrigado, man.

Comment: @RaoniBatistadeSousa dá uma olhada dentro do `for` e faz um console.log` a ambos `liBArray[i]` e `iconsArray[i]`. Dá-me ideia que não há um icon para cada liB..

Comment: Ah sim, agora sim deu certo, só mudei os seletores.

  var liB = document.querySelectorAll('#footFlex li'), 
        liBArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(liB), 
        icons = document.querySelectorAll('#footFlex li i'), 
        iconsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(icons);

Obrigado, man.